# multiple screen in Titanium Studio

Tags: iphone, titanium

I want to build an iphone app with multiple screen, but I can't seem to make it work.

Here is what I did:

**app.js**

```
var rotate = Titanium.UI.createButton({
    top:205,
    left:100,
    height:30,
    width:120,
    backgroundImage:"anim_ctrl_panel_1.png"
});

rotate.addEventListener('click', function()
{
      var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
            url:"Window1.js",
            title:"Window1"
    });

   // Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(window,{animated:true});
   window.open();
}
);
```

**Window1.js**

```
var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundImage:"photo1.png",
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
```

But when I click my button nothing happens. Could someone show what is the right way to do this.

This is what my console displays:

[UITabBarController setSelectedViewController:] only a view controller in the tab bar controller's list of view controllers can be selected.

So is there someone that can show me what is the right way to do it?

IMPORTANT: I don't want a link where to go from here, because I've been here:

[Titanium: navigation from one screen to other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450075/titanium-navigation-from-one-screen-to-other)
and in other places but I just can make this work. Thanks

Comment: Remove build from application folder and try again

Comment: Actually i got the same problem but after deleting build its work for me.

Comment: Titanium is not ready for use yet. The documentation on the net is quite poor!

Comment: Why are you creating the window again in Window1.js  file?

Comment: well, the Window1.js file should be empty?

Comment: That is all I have in Window1.js file....

Comment: nothing new. The same behaviour. And it shouldn't be empty, mister!

Comment: Your window1.js file should have `var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow; win.title= 'Tab1'; `

Comment: Do you have any tabgroup in your app.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not just open a window. There are 2 ways of doing this, either you create a Modal window, or you are using a navigation group.

One thing is for sure, you should not re-create the window in `Window1.js`. This way of implementing is actually quite wrong, and is bad for your memory.

A better way of approach is doing it with a function. (you can also do it more JavaScript OO) Add this code to Window1.js:

```
function createWindow1(){
    var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Tab 1',
        backgroundImage:"photo1.png",
        backgroundColor:'#fff',
        modal: true
    }); 
    return win;
}
```

After that, you can call it like this in app.js

```
var window = createWindow1();
```

But don't forget to include the Window1.js file first (on top of the file, or at least before the function is called)

```
Ti.include('Window1.js');
```

Now to the `open` part. As you can see I added the parameter `modal` to the window element. This would make the window open on top of other windows (this can only be done once)

A better way of doing this is using the [NavigationGroup](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.iPhone.NavigationGroup-object.html). Note that this is not for android, but for iOS only. Check for an example the documentation. (the previous link).

The structure for the code is window > navigationgroup > window. The toplevel window doesn't have to do anything, just hide the navigationbar. With the navigationgroup you can do `open(window)` and that way it will open a window iOS style (with an arrow on the top-left-corner)

Answer (score 1):

Actually what Topener recommend is 99% correct... you do not want to use the include method, you want to use a commonJS module. It is the recommended approach from Appcelerator

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium

Answer (score 0):

try this....
 add in `window1.js`

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow(); win.title = 'tab 1'; win.backgroungImage="photo1.png"; win.backgroundColor= '#fff';
```